# IIS7 + PHP + Zend - Not executing <= *pic*

Tags: php, zend-framework, iis, url-rewriting

I have PHP, IIS7, ReWrite Module for IIS and Zend all installed.

I can execute PHP pages just fine, even got PHPINFO showing up.

I setup a Zend quickstart app on IIS and when I open it this is what I see:

You can see from the source that it's not executing the <= portions.

Any idea what needs to change?

[alt text http://www.gonrad.com/200902/zendiis.jpg](http://www.gonrad.com/200902/zendiis.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable shortags in your php.ini:

```
short_opentag = on
```

However, even though Zend's examples use the open tag, for portability you really should use the full echo statement as not all webhosts allow for short_opentag. The short tag might save a bit of time typing but may actually be worse in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

make sure <? is enabled and not just <?php

if you use <?

php.ini --->short_opentag=On